# Discount to apply after coupon code

Tags: magento-1, shipping, onepage-checkout, shipping-methods, discount

I have a discount code for -100% of the shipping cost when 24 hour delivery is selected. The discount code works and deducts the amount (in this case £15.00) from the total. However this is not reflected in the table. What I wish for it to do is the following:

1. User chooses 24 hour discount
2. User enters discount code
3. discount is applied
4. Discount code is displayed in order review
5. Shipping amount is reduced from £15.00 to £0.00 to show user that the shipping discount code has worked and shipping is now £0.00

Currently the last step doesn't happen and you end up with the result in the image below:
[image]

I would like it to work as below:
[image]

I have tried adding custom javascript to scan the page every 1000ms for the -£15.00 and overwrite the shipping total to £0.00 when the discount is detected but it won't work on Magento.

Plugins used:

`onepage checkout` & `ultimate shipper`

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what version of magento1, 2? please share a little of you code and related area

Comment: magento 1, and the js code mentioned above can be found at [link](https://uat.visual-group.co.uk/centurion.js)